# how to logging Compile-time logging source generator log information in logfile in .net 6

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, serilog-aspnetcore

logging Compile-time logging source generator log info in logfile in .net 6.but in my case it can't logging.

so can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

could you first download the below packages:

```
Install-Package Serilog
Install-Package Serilog.AspNetCore
Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.File
Install-Package Serilog.Settings.Configuration
```

Program.cs:

```
using Serilog;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .WriteTo.File("Logs/logfile.log")
    .CreateLogger();

builder.Host.UseSerilog();

var app = builder.Build();

app.Run();
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs/logfile.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```